# Set Python wheel version tag dynamically

Tags: python, setuptools, python-wheel

I'm trying to integrate building of a wheel file into a Bamboo plan. Ultimately, I'd like to tie part of the version tag of the .whl file to the Bamboo build number in someway, i.e. the pre-release for version 0 would be 0.dev1, 0.dev2, 0.dev3 for successive builds.

The old egg format used to allow the `--tag_build` option, which would allow you to specify a tag that is appended to the `version` parameter defined in the `setup` function in the `setup.py` file. The `bdist_wheel` command apparently doesn't have an equivalent option.

This dashed my hopes of running `setup.py` from a script, using the Bamboo build number variable. I'm looking for any other suggestions other than either converting the build script to Powershell, or generating `setup.py` on the fly each build.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version tag in the wheel filename is just the package version number, defined by `setup.py`, and `setup.py` is a Python script with all the power of Python available to it.  Thus, `setup.py` can simply set the `version` parameter of the `setup()` function based on the `bamboo_buildNumber` environment variable:

```
import os

version = whatever_the_version_would_be_otherwise
try:
    version += '.dev' + os.environ['bamboo_buildNumber']
except KeyError:  # bamboo_buildNumber isn't defined, so we're not running in Bamboo
    pass

setup(
    version = version,
    ...
)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! This was my first attempt to add a plan to a project in Bamboo and I hadn't found all the documentation for the env variables it sets yet.

Comment: Do you know of a way to do this with either the setup.cfg or command line parameters?